# Is there a way to create a "Self-hosted" Web Site in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Similar to WCF Self Hosting.

Is there a way to create a website that is "self-hosted" within a console application or `dll`?

Probably the wrong way to ask this question, but what i'd like to do is use this website to split results as web pages without creating the website within `IIS`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very basic HTTP server is implemented by the [HttpListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) in the .NET Framework.

If you need something more powerful, have a look at [Microsoft Cassini](http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx), a simple HTTP server written in C# licensed under Ms-PL. It's basically a demo how to host the ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: Thanks! i'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have visual studio, here is an article I read a while back on how to basically snatch the VS built-in web server and use it for your own purposes:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LightIIS.aspx

Comment: I can't find the dll's they mention. Searched my entire HDD for it

Answer (score 1):

You can try Ultidev Cassini: http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Open Web Interface for .NET (OWIN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin).