# Local installation of IIS together with an application

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I want to deliver an instance of the IIS with my Win32 application to provide some ASP.NET HTML documents within this app. Can I install a local version of the IIS independent from the gloabl installation of the IIS? Can I deliver multiples installations of an IIS as I can do this with apache, e.g.? Or do I have to use the global system installation of the IIS and hook myself into an existiing website or create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following SO question and answer on "self hosting an ASP.net website".

[Is there a way to create a "Self-hosted" Web Site in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875725/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-self-hosted-web-site-in-net)