# How to run ASP.NET web applications in Web Browser from c# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, iis

I developed a Win Forms application that **searches for ASP.NET files in directories**.

The directories always contain ASP.NET files (.aspx etc.)

**How can I run the ASP.NET web app from my Win Forms using c#?**

I found the code bellow, but I can't figure out how to append the ASPX files folder.

```
//thread to start IIS
public static void Thread1()
{
    //thread for running IIS
    using (Process proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/path:""c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles"" /vpath:/asp.netwebadminfiles /port:61569 /clr:4.0 /ntlm";
        //proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        //output from the process run
        Console.Out.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

public void OpenThread()
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(IISMngr.Thread1));
    thread1.Start();
    using (Process proc1 = new Process())
    {
        proc1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
        proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = @"http://localhost:61569/asp.netwebadminfiles/Default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\FFF\AspProject\&applicationUrl=/";
        proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc1.Start();
        proc1.WaitForExit();
        //output from the process run
        Console.Out.WriteLine(proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

**"?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\FFF\AspProject\"** is where the ASP.NET Web App is located (aspx, etc.)

Comment: something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875725/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-self-hosted-web-site-in-net